# ediprolog on emacs strange behaviour

Tags: emacs, prolog, swi-prolog

I am newish to using emacs and customising it.

I am trying to install [ediprolog](https://www.metalevel.at/ediprolog/)

My `.emacs` file is:

```
custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(global-set-key [f10] 'ediprolog-dwim)

(setq load-path (cons "/home/sam/Documents/emacs/prolog" load-path))
(autoload 'run-prolog "prolog" "Start a Prolog sub-process." t)
(autoload 'prolog-mode "prolog" "Major mode for editing Prolog programs." t)
(autoload 'mercury-mode "prolog" "Major mode for editing Mercury programs." t)
(setq prolog-system 'swi)
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.pl\\'" . prolog-mode)
                                ("\\.m\\'" . mercury-mode))
                               auto-mode-alist))
```

I installed ediprolog with `M-x package-install RET ediprolog RET`

I have created a test file with `%?- member(X,[a,b,c]).` If I press `F10` and `space space space` when on this query I get the following output:

```
%?- member(X,[a,b,c]).
%@  member(X,[a,b,c]^H^H^H^H^H^H^H[a,b,c])^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H(X,[a,b,c]).^M
%@ X = a ;^M
%@ X = b ;^M
%@ X = c.^M
%@^M
```

This is clearly not correct as I have all these extra `^H` and `^M` characters.

Also if I add the line `(require 'ediprolog)` to my `.emacs` as instructed I get the following error on starting emacs:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/sam/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, ediprolog

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I also have followed the instructions at https://bruda.ca/emacs/prolog-mode_installation_guide to install the prolog-mode if that is relevant.

Comment: Side question: Why do you use `/home/sam/Documents/emacs/prolog` rather than rely on the prolog-mode that comes built-in with Emacs?

Comment: You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug RET` asking for ediprolog to handle the new escape sequences used in recent versions of SWI-Prolog.

Comment: I followed the instructions here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/GnuEmacs.html which recommended to use this version.

Comment: Could you contact the swi-prolog people pointing out that these instructions have been outdated for a few years (the mode that comes with Emacs is a more recent version of that of Stefan Bruda).

Comment: Another source that recommends this version is here: https://www.metalevel.at/pceprolog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by SWI-Prolog's recent switch to the **editline** library, whereas it previously used **readline** by default.

## The issue is now solved.

SWI-Prolog 7.5.1 and later contain a [**change**](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/commit/044aabc5a8f2d801f233227622472e235e28310a) that make `ediprolog` work again, without requiring any upgrades or configuration changes of Emacs or `ediprolog`.

Also the upcoming stable version (7.4) of SWI-Prolog ships with this change.

Therefore, only very few versions (notably 7.5.0 and 7.4-rc1) are affected by this problem.

---

If you are using a version of SWI-Prolog where this issue shows up, here are possible workarounds:

One way to solve this is to put the following in your `~/.swiplrc` initialization file:

> ```
> :- set_prolog_flag(readline, readline).
> ```

This should yield a working `ediprolog`, assuming you have `readline` installed.

Alternatively, you can also put:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(readline, false).
```

in your `~/.swiplrc` initialization file. However, this completely *disables* the line editing facilities of SWI-Prolog also if you invoke it on the system terminal. You can of course use `-f none` to ignore the initialization file in such cases.

Alternatively, you can also put the following in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq ediprolog-program-switches '("-g" "set_prolog_flag(readline, false)"))
```

If your version of SWI-Prolog is sufficiently recent, these workarounds are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

For the problem with `(require 'ediprolog)`, you simply need to add `(package-initialize)` earlier in your `~/.emacs` (recent Emacsen will do this for you).  But since you installed it from ELPA, you shouldn't need to `require` it explicitly: `ediprolog-dwim` should autoload for you anyway.